# Getting 403 Forbidden Error for REST add list item

Tags: rest, updatelistitems

I'm getting continuous 403 forbidden errors when trying to add a list item.
Here's what I have so far

```
 $.ajax({
            url: webUrl,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(item),
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("failure");
            }
     });
```

Comment: are you querying a separate domain/webapp? what version are you on?

Comment: i'm querying a list on sharepoint through a webapp located on sharepoint. using 2013 sharepoint

Comment: is it across site collections?

Comment: Try to copy your webUrl and then paste in the browser and see if the endpoint is available. If you could share the URL whitout server address, only the REST endpoint would be useful too.

Comment: I’m not sure if it’s on site collections. How can I find out?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
            $.ajax({
                url: webUrl + "/_api/lists/getbytitle('---ListName--')?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName",
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                success: onEntitySuccess,
                error: onEntityFailure
            });
        function onEntitySuccess(data) {
            listItemEntity = data.d.ListItemEntityTypeFullName;
        }
        function onEntityFailure(err) {
            alert(err.statusText);
        }
```

Comment: is this to post?

Comment: what is this to post?

Comment: i'm trying to add a new list item. shouldn't that be post?

Comment: it for to add list item to list (

Comment: try by replacing you ajax call with this, hope it will work.

Comment: Nope... doesn't work. I'm trying to POST not GET

Comment: try the other one that is posted ...

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 try {
                    var queryUrl = Url + "/_api/lists/GetByTitle('--ListName--')/items";
                    $.ajax({
                        url: queryUrl,
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        data: JSON.stringify(
                            {
                                '__metadata': {
                                    'type': listItemEntity
                                },
                                'Name' : CTName,
                                'ListName': CTListName,
}),
                    headers: {
                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                    }, success: data,
                    error: data
                });
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert("Exception" + ex.message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code doesn't even works, there a lot of sintaxe errors.

Comment: tell me those syntax errors ..?